# route view for new IPs?

Tags: route

The route view method is not working for me

```
telnet route-views.routeviews.org
(logged in with user "rviews")

route-views>show ip bgp 173.244.44.0 | inc 10464
route-views>show ip bgp 173.244.44.0            
% Network not in table
route-views>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with your peers/upstreams to make sure they are seeing the announcement.  They may need to adjust their filters to allow your IP addresses to propagate.

I don't see the route announced on any of our routers as of 2010-04-23 00:00.